# How to make emacs only make new window instead of sometimes new frame?

Tags: emacs

When calling ediff, run-python and some other commands, emacs will open a new frame, but I want emacs to open new window instead, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dunno why someone voted you down. Perhaps s?he thought you should have looked first in the Ediff manual (which I too recommend).

   a. Command `ediff-toggle-multiframe` toggles between using multiple frames and a single frame (multiple windows).

   b. The Ediff manual says also: **"See `ediff-window-setup-function` for details on how to make
   either of these modes the default one."**
2. You will need to check whether Python mode similarly provides options or commands to control the window/frame behavior.
3. If Emacs is *always* opening a new frame for everything, then make sure you do not have a non-`nil` value for option `pop-up-frames`.

Comment: For ediff, I use `(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)`

Comment: (setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain) is ok.